# WebDriver calls using web-component-tester?

Tags: polymer, web-component-tester

I'm trying to write some functional tests using Polymer's web-component-tester.  I need to enter in some values into a search filter, triggering an `onkeyup` event.  Can I make calls to WebDriver from a Mocha test?

Comment: wondering if you found a solution to this?

Comment: Not yet, maybe you could post an issue ticket to the Github repo?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look on this repo: https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-test-helpers 
It's Polymer's test helpers which will help you to mock interactions inside the component.

```
var element = fixture('basic');
var input = Polymer(element).querySelector('input[type="search"]');
MockInteractions.pressAndReleaseKeyOn(input, 65, [], 'A');
MockInteractions.pressEnter(input);
```

Take a look on an example test case here: https://github.com/PolymerElements/gold-cc-expiration-input/blob/95fa373eab5ddb557a2196d4186c283726b8c5f1/test/basic.html

Comment: I'm not working on this project anymore so I don't know if this is the correct answer.  If someone else can chime in and let me know if it works, I will mark it as accepted : )